# PHP Reminder system using cronjob

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I try to create a `PHP` reminder system

I have a table for tasks in this table i have many information and i have the planning end date for this task

I have create a new table name `tbl_remtask` this table contain the id of the task and the reminder time and some other information

The reminder time is an integer

My HTML Code:

```
<label>Reminder *</label>
     <select name="txt_reminder" class="form-control" required>
     <option value="">--SELECT--</option>
     <option value="300">5 minutes before</option> 
     <option value="900">15 minutes before</option> 
     <option value="1800">30 minutes before</option>
     <option value="3600">1 hour before</option> 
     <option value="7200">2 hours before</option> 
     <option value="86400">1 day before</option>
     <option value="172800">2 day before</option>
     <option value="604800">1 week before</option>     
     </select>
```

My PHP Code:

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"
select 
remtask.*,
task.db_pdd,
user.db_email,
concat(user.db_fname,' ' ,user.db_lname) as name
from tbl_remtask as remtask
left join tbl_task as task
on
task.db_taskid=remtask.db_taskid
left join tbl_user as user
on
user.db_uid=task.db_userid
where 
remtask.db_send='0'
")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $reminder=$row['db_reminder'];
        $pdd=$row['db_pdd'];
        $reminderTime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-$reminder second", strtotime($pdd)));
        $dateNow=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
       if($dateNow==$reminderTime){
        //send mail
}else{
        //do somthing else
}
```

To run this reminder i will create a `cronjob` the problem i have that i have a reminder in time that mean as you see in the html code i have a reminder before 5 min,15 min,30 min,1 hour,2 hours

If the code run after that time in 1 min or second i will not receive an email.

This problem don't appear for 1 day,2 days,1 week because we don't have a specific time here.

I think to run a `cronjob` each minute but can that make any problem in the server?

And Is their any other idea to do that ??!!

Comment: It is perfectly normal to run a cron job every minute.

Comment: @BrianGottier thank you